# Why I have two headers? And how to remove upper header?

Tags: java, android, xml, uinavigationbar

I wanted to create a "registration" navigation bar but "RegistrationForm" is also visible. How to remove it?
MainActivity.java

```
   MaterialToolbar toolbar;
    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopup(toolbar);
        }
    });


}


public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.other, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24dp"
            app:title="@string/page_title" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Note: A RecyclerView can also be used -->
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Scrollable content -->

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Popup.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/more"/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMr0r.jpg)
I have two header(navigation bar) one below the other. But I cannot get rid of upper header(navigation bar).Which is original header. So i try to figure out how to remove upper header

Answer (score 0):

Go to your styles folder (under the res --> values ---> styles folder )and change your Material Theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`

```
<

    resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"> ...
```

.